# How to update list dynamically in php or ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dynamic

I have a concept of a website that would need the elements of list to auto update like go up and down in an animated way. I have found solutions to do this by `setTimeout()` method to run in the list section but that requires the page or a particular section of page to refresh at interval which would ruin the concept.

Here is the image depicting the concept:

[Image](http://tinypic.com?ref=55mkd1)

Comment: I'd recommend SignalR, but don't know the php equivalent.  Either way, please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @nerdyist  Sorry if the description is not clear enough.The question is I need a method in php or ajax so that it would take some data feed(say json data feed) and/or conditional logic and shift the elements of a list up and down dynamically and in an animated fashion.